# How to access the same subkey in every key on a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, multidimensional-array, key, dictionary-comprehension

I'm new to coding (either in english, so sorry if I misspell) and I got curious about a dictionary funcionality. To be more clear let me give an example:

```
dictionary = {"person_1": {"city": _, "age": 18}
              "person_2": {"city": _, "age": 25}
              "person_3": {"city": _, "age": 57}
               ...}
```

I would like to know if there is someway to access every "city" or "age" (maybe to sum ages or something). I thought about a loop however do it at once without having to acess every person would be more efficient. Any help ?

Comment: how would you write it, if it was `{"person_1": 18, "person_2": 25, "person_3": 57, ...}`?

Comment: What do you want to do with each value? Sum the ages? (You say you want to do multiple things.)

Comment: You will have to access every person in order to do this. If you are working in a non-parallel environment this will require some form of loop (although that loop might not always be apparent to you as a programmer). To sum up all the ages you could e.g. use `result = sum(person["age"] for person in dictionary.values())`. In a parallel environment you could use a concept called loop unrolling and calculate a so called prefix sum but that is not really beginner friendly and overkill for this little dictionary (it would be slower for small dictionaries).

Comment: If that was the case I would probably sum(dictionary) but other informations are important too. Maybe creating a different list would be better ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, dictionaries have a  [`.values()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/) method, let me show you an example:

here i have a dictionaries of cities:

```
{"city1":{"name":"Italy"}
 "city2":{"name":"United States"}}
```

to get the list where i have only the names, you can use `.values()`,turn it into a list since `DictValues` instances are immutable

so in your case:

```
dictionary = {"person_1": {"city": "Washington DC", "age": 18}
          "person_2": {"city": "Rome", "age": 25}
          "person_3": {"city": "Berlin", "age": 57}
}

values=list(dictionary.values())
print("values:",values)
```

output:

```
values: [{'city': 'Washington DC', 'age': 18}, {'city': 'Rome', 'age': 25}, {'city': 'Berlin', 'age': 57}]
```

to do the sum of the ages, without loops you could use the `map` function to get all the ages and then, do the sum with the `sum` function

```
dictionary = {"person_1": {"city": "Washington DC", "age": 18}
          "person_2": {"city": "Rome", "age": 25}
          "person_3": {"city": "Berlin", "age": 57}
}
ages=list(map(lambda x:x["age"],dictionary.values()))
sumofages=sum(ages)
print("sum of ages:",sumofages)
```

output:

```
sum of ages: 100
```

Comment: But I would have to make a loop anyway to sum ages, right ?

Comment: no, i'll add that to the answer, thanks

Comment: added, it would be appreciated a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you could sum all 'ages' in a dictionary with the structure shown in the question:

```
_ = 'Rio de Janeiro'

dictionary = {"person_1": {"city": _, "age": 18},
              "person_2": {"city": _, "age": 25},
              "person_3": {"city": _, "age": 57}}

sum_of_ages = sum(d['age'] for d in dictionary.values())

print(sum_of_ages)
```

**Output:**

```
100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d1 = {"person_1": {"city": 'LA', "age": 18},
              "person_2": {"city": 'SD', "age": 25},
              "person_3": {"city": 'NY', "age": 57},
             }
```

Traditional way:

```
_sum =0
for p in d1.values():
    _sum+=p['age']
```

_sum:
100

List comprehension:

```
_sum2 = sum([p['age'] for p in d1.values()])
```

_sum2:
100